# How to bring a View to the top of a tableview content view in StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I want to build a view about user which display user information and some small functions .User information will be shown in the top of the view and there is a list containing the small functions.

In the storyboard I dragged a `TableView` to the ViewController, and dragged a view that will display the user information. Things becomes different when I pushed a cell into the tableview. The `Prototype Cells` will bring upward and occupied the place of `User Information view`.

Just like this :
[image]

**How Can I bring the user information view to the top of `Tableview`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about dropping the cell first in the tableview and then dropping the view above the cell inside the tableview, Here is a screenshot
[image]

As you can see the `UIView` is red colour and is inside the tableview and above the `cell` which is orange colour.

Or you can put the `UIView` totally above the tableview,which one will suit you better.

Comment: This is the way you can do it.

Comment: It works. Drag the cell in tableview first then drag a UIView just above the `Prototype cells`.

Comment: And there is another thing should pay attention to. After dropping the `UIView` above the prototype cells, you CAN NOT drop any components above the `prototype cell`, and the tableview is divided into two side : `Prototype cell` part and `View` that we added part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bringSubviewToFront`

If `informationView` is a subview of `self.view`

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(informationView)
```

If `informationView` is a subview of `tableView`

```
tableView.bringSubviewToFront(informationView)
```

Comment: It not works. And I think it will never work although `cells` and my `information` view are in the same UI level when inspecting in the `Reveal` application.

Comment: You can `bringSubviewToFront` from superview every create new cell. But it's not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

[image]you can put any view as header view on tablview

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


return 44.0;
```

}

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


searchBaar= [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 44.0f)];
searchBaar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searchBaar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
searchBaar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
searchBaar.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeySearch;
searchBaar.placeholder = @"Search";
searchBaar.delegate = self;
searchBaar.showsCancelButton = NO;
searchBaar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];


return searchBaar;
```

}

Comment: I want to use storyboard in order to using the auto layout. Or is there any way to place the header view in the Storyboard?

Comment: you can add simply this code in tableview delegate methods